# Can Android device be used as USB webcam for full-HD, 30fps video source for Skype calls via PC?

Tags: usb, webcam

Have found some apps that allow an Android device s.a. a Smartphone with good camera to be used as a USB webcam, when used of ADB over USB. However they seem to limit the video source to be fairly low quality i.e. mostly little better than VGA or if higher-resolution then at low fps.

Is there anyway to tether an Android device to a PC, over USB while using the device camera as a USB webcam working at FullHD (1080p) at 25-30fps, that could be used for doing Skype (or Skype for Business) calls ? I would like to use this setup for a live-demo. I know that I could go out and buy a dedicated webcam, but trying to avoid it if possible. My PC has an inbuilt cam, but it is 720p (not very good) and for the demo I need to be able to tilt, swivel, pan the camera - not very convenient when using inbuilt PC webcam, but fairly easy for an Android phone, mounted on a tripod.

Comment: http://www.skipser.com/p/2/p/android-as-webcam.html

Comment: https://gadgets.ndtv.com/mobiles/features/how-to-use-your-phone-as-a-webcam-617643